# Clarification between Polymer app layout elements and similar paper elements

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component, paper-elements

I have been working using many of the elements provided by the Polymer team. I have seen documentation that shows using app-layout elements and others that show the same thing achieved using paper elements.

For example `paper-drawer-panel` is very similar to `app-drawer`. The paper element appears to have more configuration options and allows for multiple `paper-drawer-panel` elements embedded within each other as opposed to the less flexible `app-drawer`.

```
<paper-drawer-panel>
    <div drawer> Drawer panel... </div>
    <div main> Main panel... </div>
</paper-drawer-panel>
```

vs.

```
<main>Main panel....</main>
<app-drawer>Drawer panel... </app-drawer>
```

Is there a reason to prefer `app-layout` elements over the similar yet more flexible paper elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `<app-*>` elements were developed later in response to requests for standard templates for apps.  I suspect some of it is just name changing to make it easier to understand.

In particular I have been using

```
<app-header-layout>
  <app-header
    fixed
    effects="waterfall">
    <app-toolbar>
    ...
    </app-toolbar>
 </app-header>
 ... my main content
</app-header-layout>
```

with great effect.  You can actually add several toolbars and some of the effects allow fading from one toolbar to the other as the headers scroll up (including a background image that fades away).

My `<app-toolbar>` contains all sorts of things including drop down menus.

I also found it easier like this to understand how to make lazy loading work.  In fact my content only contains a "session manager" element and a "pages" element, the latter of which is only lazily loaded after the session manager has successfully validated a user (via cookie or login). That pages element has an embedded `<iron-pages>` and `<app-location>` and `<app-route>` to do all management of the application post login.